# ASP.NET MVC / C# - String to valid URL characters?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, url

I don't know how to ask this, and I don't know what it is called either so I'll just describe what I want to achieve.

In the database, some articles' title originaly has spaces:

```
my title with spaces
```

But in the url, spaces are replaced by other characters such as plus sign (+) or underscore (_)

```
http://www.mydomain.com/mycontroller/myaction/my_title_with_spaces
```

or

```
http://www.mydomain.com/mycontroller/myaction/my+title+with+spaces
```

Now, how do you do that in C#? Or is there any helper in ASP.NET MVC that can do something like that?

Let say we achieved the said URL, is there any risk that two unique titles become the same in the URL? Please consider these titles:

```
Title's
Titles
```

after parsing, they became the same

Titles
   Titles

This will be a problem when retrieving the article from the database since I'll get two results, one for "Title" and one for "Title's".

Comment: Characters like ' should be unique. For the url problem, I am not entirely sure. I don't entirely understand your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would implement that functionality like this:

**1. When creating a new article, generate the URL representation based on the title.**

Use a function that converts the title for a suitable representation.
For example, the title "This is an example" might generate something like "This_is_an_example".

This is up to you. You can create a function that parses the title with rules you define, or use an existing one if it suits better your problem.

**2. Ensure the URL representation is unique**

If it's going to be an ID, it must be unique. So, when creating new articles you must query your database for the resulting URL representation. If you get a result from the database, it means the newly created article generated the same representation as one of the already created articles. Add something to it so it remains unique.

This could be something like "This_is_an_example_2". In this case, we added the "_2" to the end of the generated representation so it differs from the already existing one. Once more, with each change you have to ensure this representation remains unique.

**3. Save the created ID in the database, along with the article data**

In the database be sure to save the "This_is_an_example" ID and relate it to the article. Maybe even as the table primary key?

**4. Query the database for the correct article**

Now, about showing a site visitor the correct article:
When a visitor asks for the following resource, for example:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/mycontroller/myaction/this_is_an_example_2
```

Extract the URL part that identifies the article, in this case "this_is_an_example_2".

When you have that, you have the identifier of the article in the database. So, you can query the database for the article with the "this_is_an_example_2" ID and show the article's content to the user.

This might involve some URL rewriting. Unfortunately I'm unable to help you with that in asp.NET. Some search on the subject will surely help you.

Comment: Personally, I would avoid creating unique names and just use id's for uniqueness, but also add in a text slug for SEO purposes. Like what Stackoverflow does. The ID is unique and the url works just fine without the text at the end. The text is for cosmetic purposes.

Comment: @SergioTapia, so should I avoid putting title on the URL?

Comment: I agree, it's a matter of approach. I've never implemented said functionality and just gave an example from the top of my head.

Comment: You shouldn't rely on the title for uniqueness. The title on the URL is mostly used for SEO purposes (as stated by Sergio), and it might be a better approach to use it together with an ID rather then alone. If you're not familiarized with SEO (Search engine optimization) I suggest you do some research on the subject first in order to understand why titles are used in URL's.